# Blender 2.80 GLTF Import and Export Issues

Tags: export, import, gltf

I am having an issue with Blender 2.80 on Ubuntu 19.10 Linux. If I attempt to import any GLTF files, Blender crashes immediately and I can't find any logs in my /tmp/ directory.

The second part of the issue is a specific .blend scene I'm working with. When I try to export the file using the native GLTF/GLB exporter on Blender 2.80 I am unable to see textures in online GLTF viewers (like https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/). If I export as seperate GLTF + textures + bin I see no textures folder.

Here are the files I am working with: https://send.firefox.com/download/3ca124498928be3c/#xYGd--ZDuHM0fq_x_lrCnw.

Appreciate any thoughts on this and whether I should report this as a bug.

Comment: For importing glTF, have you tried a newer copy of Blender than 2.80?  For exporting textures, glTF supports a PBR-based material system, but not arbitrary texture hookups.  [See the Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html) for more detailed information on how to export materials to glTF.

Comment: I tried updating to the 2.82a version and it the import works perfectly now. Thanks! I am still a bit new to blender and the PBR-based material system. When I import my .blend scene there is no Principled BSDF node in the node diagram. Is there a way I can add it in?